# Vuetify Firebase Delete Document from Subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

The below code is supposed to delete the document that is sent to the function as argument. Unfortunately the code doesn't work and not sure what is wrong in the code. I have tried with different Firebase functions and code structure but nothing really worked. Can somebody please guide me to make the code working?

There are 4 levels in the FB datastore: Collection_L1 > Document_L1 > subcollection > Document_L2 but I want to delete a specific document from Document_L2 without deleting any other documents or collections.

```
deletePubProfi(cProfile) {
    firebase.db.collection('UsageProfile').doc('favourites').getCollections()
    .then(collections => {
      collections.forEach(collection => {
        collection.get().then(docs => {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
                if(doc.id == cProfile.id)
                    {doc.delete()}
            } 
        })
      })
    }) 
},
```

Comment: "nothing really worked" is really hard to help with. Is there any error message? If not, it's most helpful if you can debug locally and share the results of that with us. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I meant by that that I have used many function options to make at least the outer loop working. If I use 'getCollection' or 'listCollection' I get error that the function is wrong. However, if I used 'get' which is used to get the documents from collection and not the other way around, I get the error in the next loop that 'collections.foreach.......' this function is wrong.

Comment: Sorry @Embryo-coder, but I'm not really sure I follow. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal repro of where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the error message you get - and/or the result you get after debugging as I explained in my first comment.

Comment: I'm sorry that you didn't understand my comments. Do you see 'getCollections' function in my code, if yes, that is the outer or top most loop that I was talking about and where I'm stuck. I also mentioned the error that I'm getting :'function is wrong'. Does it now make sense? Do you know the Firestore function that lists subcollection from the document?